# How to make relative URL in JavaScript with PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, kohana

I'm trying to centralize configuration files in my php app (kohana framework). My target is one config file - included to main controller, "Controller_Welcome". Here is code:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

// configuration

define('SITE_TITLE', 'something');
define('MEDIA_DIR', 'something');
define('SEPARATOR', 'something');
define('IMG_PATH', MEDIA_DIR.'images/');
define('TEMPLATE', 'something');
define('URL_ABSOLUTE', 'http://localhost/');
define('CONTACT_EMAIL', 'something');
define('LOCAL_PATH', 'public_html/');
```

My js script contain an URL which I want to merge with php LOCAL_PATH. Code:

```
 $(function () {
     $("#submit").click(function () {
         var message = $("#message").val();
         var data = 'message=' + message;
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/index.php/shoutbox", // <------- this is what i mean
             data: data,
             success: function (html) {
                 $("#message").val("");
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
});
```

Any ideas how to introduce configuration constant/variable from php file to my js (ajax query)?

Comment: `<script>var LOCAL_PATH = '<?php echo LOCAL_PATH; ?>';</script>` in the view file before the ajax call.

Comment: You could create variables on the front-end which contain the back-end values. If PHP serve the pages anyway a simple `<script>var myJavascriptVariable = "<?php eacho $myPHPVariable; ?>";</script>` will do before your JS file includes. Or you can configure your server so that php works inside JS files too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(function () {
         $("#submit").click(function () {
             var message = $("#message").val();
             var data = "message=" + message;
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "<?= URL::site('shoutbox', $this->request, TRUE); ?>",
                 data: data,
                 success: function (html) {
                     $("#message").val("");
                 }
             });
             return false;
         });
    });
```

Comment: that's not really what i need, your code requires parsing every JS file as php script right? I think it's not as fast as solution mentioned above.

Comment: You cannot read you defined variables from php. You need to generate the script with php.

Comment: then take a look at comments to my question, you needn't to parse js as php to reach variable